# How to allow HTTPS site to access HTTP enables site in Dynamics CRM 2016 on-prem?

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2016

I am trying to add `autocomplete` functionality for `Country/Region` field on account form in **on-prem environment of Dynamics CRM 2016** by [following the post](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt607648.aspx). My CRM environment is `HTTPS` enabled [here in post](http://blog.sonomapartners.com/2016/01/dynamics-crm-2016-turn-any-text-field-into-an-auto-complete.html) it is mentioned that to add autocomplete functionality you have to allow access to **http** sites from **HTTPS** enabled site.

I want to know how can I get this job done?

Answer (score 0):

That's not supported in IE by default (you'll get a security exception) and I wouldn't do it cause it could introduce security flaws. Vice-versa is not the same tho, you could access a HTTPS site from a HTTP, that's not a problem.